# Typescript: Assign prop type to component prop in a custom component in React Native

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, types, interface

I am creating a custom reusable component which can take in another Component as a prop to used as a children. I want to add the type dynamically form the data which is passed into this component.

The best reference is `<FlatList>`. I need exactly how `<FlatList>` is created. We have a `renderItem` prop for it where it will take in that component and pass the `data`'s type to the `renderItem` function.

Example:

```
<FlatList
    data={['str1', 'str2', 'str3']} // Array type is string[] here
    renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item}</Text>} // The item type is string here />
```

Desired Component:

```
<MyComponent
    data={[ { name: 'abc', age: 5 }, { name: 'xyz', age: 5 } ]} // Array is a custom type User[]
    renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.name}</Text>} /> // The item is User type
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FlatList` is using generic parameters to achieve the desired result. You can create a custom component that using the same mechanism. Here's an example:

```
type MyComponentProps<T> = {
    data: T[]
    renderItem: (item: T) => React.ReactNode
}

const MyComponent = <T,>({data, renderItem}: MyComponentProps<T>) => {
    // you code 
}
```

Hope it's helps

Comment: Great! this worked. Is it possible to add another type to the `renderItem: (item: T & { text: string }) => React.ReactNode` and export this? -> `T & { text: string }`

Comment: I'm sorry if I misunderstood your request earlier. But yes, you can extend the T generic however you like inside the declaration of your props.

Comment: Your understanding was correct. That was a follow up question. Got it working. Thanks again.